# How to stop boost::ioservice on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

**Solution Found**
I am useing VS2013, boost 1.59.0
I have the following example from `boost c++ application development cookbook`
I have a problem to stop `boost::ioservice` on Windows. I now found a workaround way to stop it which is using `ios_.stopped()`.

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

namespace detail
{

    template <class T>
    struct task_wrapped
    {
    private:
        T task_unwrapped_;
    public:
        explicit task_wrapped(const T& task_unwrapped)
            : task_unwrapped_(task_unwrapped)
        {}
        void operator()() const
        {
            // resetting interruption
            try
            {
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            }
            catch (const boost::thread_interrupted&){}

            try
            {
                // Executing task
                task_unwrapped_();
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
            catch (const boost::thread_interrupted&)
            {
                std::cerr << "Thread interrupted\n";
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                std::cerr << "Unknown exception\n";
            }
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    task_wrapped<T> make_task_wrapped(const T& task_unwrapped)
    {
        return task_wrapped<T>(task_unwrapped);
    }
} // namespace detail

class tasks_processor;
tasks_processor* pProcessor = nullptr;
class tasks_processor : private boost::noncopyable {
    boost::asio::io_service ios_;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
    tasks_processor()
        : ios_()
        , work_(ios_)
    {}
public:
    static tasks_processor& get()
    {
        if (pProcessor == nullptr)
        {
            pProcessor = new tasks_processor;
        }
        return *pProcessor;
    }

    template <class T>
    inline void push_task(const T& task_unwrapped) {
        ios_.post(detail::make_task_wrapped(task_unwrapped));
    }

    void start() {
        ios_.run();
    }
    void stop() {
        ios_.stop();
    }
    bool IsStopped() {
        return ios_.stopped();
    }
}; // tasks_processor

int g_val = 0;
void func_test()
{
    if (tasks_processor::get().IsStopped())
        return;
    ++g_val;
    if (g_val == 3)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Just checking");
    }
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    if (g_val == 10)
    {
        // Emulation of thread interruption.
        // Will be caught and won't stop execution.
        throw boost::thread_interrupted();
    }
    if (g_val == 90)
    {
        tasks_processor::get().stop();
    }
}


int main()
{
    static const std::size_t tasks_count = 100;
    // stop() is called at 90
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(tasks_count > 90);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < tasks_count; ++i)
    {
        tasks_processor::get().push_task(&func_test);
    }

    // We can also use result of boost::bind call
    // as a task
    tasks_processor::get().push_task(
        boost::bind(std::plus<int>(), 2, 2) // counting 2 + 2
        );

    // Processing was not started.
    assert(g_val == 0);
    // Will not throw, but blocks till
    // one of the tasks it is owning
    // calls stop().
    tasks_processor::get().start();
    assert(g_val == 90);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the variable `g_val` equal to 100 which means that `ios_.stop();` is not working. I run as debug and this command has been called. How to stop `boost::ioservice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io_service::stop()` just changes the state of the io_service's event loop, it causes the `io_service::run()` call to return as soon as possible. It's not documented whether `stop()` cancel already queued handlers, it seems it's OS dependent according to this [post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Asio-Does-stop-cancel-handlers-post-ed-to-io-service-td4648918.html). So when `g_val == 90`, `io_service::stop()` gets called, but remaining `func_test()` may still get executed.

Comment: Do you know any workaround method to stop the `ioservice` on windows? I have tried the link you provided but it is not working /.\

Comment: maybe you can destroy the `io_service` after `stop()`, [the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service._io_service) says, on destruction of it, uninvoked handler objects that were scheduled for deferred invocation on the `io_service`, or any associated strand, are destroyed. If that doesn't work, use a `boost::atomic<bool>` flag to indicate if `io_service` is running.